# Facebook graph API/ likes and posts on users wall

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I'm using facebook graph API to "like" some content on other FBPage. But when I do it there is no notification on users wall. So my question is: Do I have to post to the wall something like: "User xxxx likes yyyy" separately?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the activity Log ? It must be showing there?

Some times it does happen that likes do not show immediately or even not at all on the timeline. Happened once or twice while testing of my canvas app.

Comment: When I am viewing the page with content that I liked it shows that I did. But there is no mentions on my user page about it. I did like some content more than few weeks ago, so it's not because of some delays.